# Trouble with Scilab "print" instruction

Tags: file, printing, formatting, overwrite, scilab

Trying to debug a program in Scilab, I inserted a couple
of "print" instructions to track what is going on.

At first, I used the %io(2) output "file" which, according
to the Help, stands for the console. Nothing happened.

Then I used an actual filename:

print("C:\Leszek\Xprmnt\scl\Ovsjanko\K3ScilabLog.txt", "START! \n \n \n \n GOING \n")

which does print to that file, but when the dust has settled
and I want to inspect the file what I find inside is just the last
message (just before the program crashed), even though there should
have been others before it, including the "START" etc in the quote above.

Apparently, every print command reopens the file for writing as a clean slate,
overwriting whatever was in it before. Looking into Help and online docs
I didn't find any options or parameters that I could use to change this.

What I want is, obviously, the output from all my print commands since the
beginning of the program, either on the console or in a text file.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `disp("some text")` or `mprintf("format",var1,...,varn)`, both will display on the console. If you need to write in a file use `fd = mopen("file.txt")` then `mfprint(fd,"format",var1,...,varn)`.